# Is there a notification platform that supports both mobile apps with Xamarin and Web Browser with Javascript

Tags: xamarin, push-notification, amazon-sns, pusher, web-notifications

I'm looking for a Notification platform which will enable me to send notifications to any platform like Web Browser, iOS and Android. Only distinction that I have is we are using Xamarin for mobile development.

First I looked to Pusher.com. It is super easy to implement and debug, I loved it. But when it comes to Xamarin platform, I couldn't find a good and trustable SDK for Xamarin. There are Objective-C and Java libraries but no supported library for Xamarin.

Then I checked to AWS SNS for mobile support, it can integrate with GCM and Apple Push Notifications so it will work with Xamarin. But my problem is Web Browser support, I couldn't find a way of integrating SNS with JavaScript like I do in Pusher.com. There isn't any trigger event that is fired when new message has been published to SNS Topic.

So in nutshell, I cannot use Pusher.com for Xamarin apps due to library support but web browser notifications are working, I cannot use AWS SNS for web browser notifications but it has GCM and Apple Push Notification support.

Is there anything I'm missing ? I want one reliable notification platform that supports all my needs, if you know could you please share it with me.

Answer (score 0):

PushSharp is the ticket.  It supports push notifications for iOS, Android, Blackberry and Windows Phone.

https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp

Answer (score 0):

You can try Parse, it support Xamarin! (and i think web browser notification isn't a problem with this platform). It is free. More info at : https://parse.com/docs

Comment: I have already checked Parse.com. It only supports sending a notification over JavaScript not receiving. SNS also can send notifications but there is no way receiving a notification. Take a look at here: https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#push-notifications-receiving-pushes